# jQuery Form Wizard not submitting (or appears not to be)

Tags: jquery, jquery-form-wizard

I have a jQuery form that goes through each step fine, but it does not appear to submit. Here is the code:

```
        $(function(){
            $("#demoForm").formwizard({ 
                formPluginEnabled: true,
                validationEnabled: true,
                focusFirstInput : true,
                textNext: 'Next',
                formOptions :{
                    url: 'submit.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){$("#status").fadeTo(500,1,function(){ $(this).html(responseText).fadeTo(5000, 0); })},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSubmit: function(data){$("#data").html("data sent to the server: " + $.param(data));},
                    resetForm: false
                }   
             }
            );
```

the BeforeSubmit event triggers, but the success never triggers. The documentation on http://thecodemine.org/ points to here: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object, and suggests that every option available on malsup.com is available for jQuery Form Wizard.

Any idea why this the status div is never getting updated?

Thanks!

Edit:

Updated JS:

```
$(function () {
$("#demoForm").formwizard({
    formPluginEnabled: true,
    validationEnabled: true,
    focusFirstInput: true,
    textNext: 'Next',
    remoteAjax: {
        "cc": { // add a remote ajax call when moving next from the second step
            url: 'submit.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#status").fadeTo(500, 1, function () {
                    $(this).html(responseText).fadeTo(5000, 0)
                });
            }
        }
    },
    formOptions: {
        success: function (data) {
            $("#status").fadeTo(500, 1, function () {
                $(this).html(responseText).fadeTo(5000, 0);
            })
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: function (data) {
            $("#data").html("data sent to the server: " + $.param(data));
        },
        resetForm: false
    }
});
```

I now see in my apache logs that the script is calling submit.php, but it doesnt seem to be putting the response on the page.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in your console? If not, are you getting a successful response from `submit.php` (Status Code 200)? If it is successful, what is the response from that file?

Comment: Updated my post. Should answer your questions. Also, no JS errors in console.

Comment: Well, you didn't answer my second question.  Are you getting a successful response from the server. Your logs might indicate that the script called your `submit.php`, but do you know if the server responded with a 200 response?  Also, did you set a breakpoint inside your success callback (right before the `$("#status")...` part?  Did it ever hit that breakpoint?

Comment: So I got rid of the updating the status div and just put a window.alert("Done") and that is not triggering either. The HTTP logs indicate that they sent a 200 status message though.

Comment: But interestingly enough, every time I refresh the page, that event is triggered....

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle.net of it please?

Comment: having problems posting to jsfiddle because everything is internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue in a very terrible way. Created an Ajax function and called it using the beforeSubmit option. I dont recommend anyone do this, but as it appears that the success form option does not work, its really all I had left to do.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue - but managed to get this working. Key was to ensure that the data was returned as JSON.

I am using node.js and express so simply had to do the following:

```
res.json({status: 'ok'});
```